# É semivogal a letra "u" em "hierarquia"?

Tags: semivogal

Uma das regras para classificar uma letra como semivogal é que a mesma deve ter som de *u* ou de *i*. Na palavra *hierarquia*, a letra *u*, na sílaba *qui*, não tem som nenhum. Ou seja, parece-me uma objeção válida dizer que a letra *u*, nesse caso, não é semivogal, pois não tem som de *u* ou *i*. Está essa análise correcta? Teria a letra *u* outra classificação nesse caso?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A letra *U* não é foneticamente nem uma vogal nem uma semivogal na ***hierarquia***. *U* não é utilizado individualmente mas faz parte do dígrafo *QU* cujo papel é manter o /k/ som em frente das vogais *I* e *E* : /ieɾaʁˈkiɐ/. Este *U* é chamado [letra diacrítica](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letra_diacr%C3%ADtica), assim como o *H* após *C*, *N* ou *L*.

Existem, contudo, palavras como ***tranquilo*** em que o *U* é pronunciado na sequência *Q**U**I*. Neste caso, *U* é usado como uma semivogal: /tɾɐ̃ˈkwilu/

Finalmente, a letra *U* nunca é pronunciada como la vogal /u/ na sequência *QU*.

Comment: Sabes se a letra "u" tem alguma classificação nesse caso?

Comment: A letra do alfabeto *U*, que é uma vogal, não deve ser confundida com os fonemas que pode representar. Quando falamos de semi-vogais, estamos a falar de fonemas, não de letras. *U* depois de *Q* é um pouco como o *H* encontrado em *CH*, *LH* ou *NH*. O seu papel é modificar a pronúncia da consoante anterior, chama-se diacrítica.

Comment: Boas-vindas ao Portuguese SE, jlliagre. Ótima primeira postagem, e ótima clarificação no comentário acima — em particular, acabo de aprender com ele o conceito de "letra diacrítica" — que sugiro que você inclua na resposta (nunca é demais enfatizar que essa é uma discussão fonética).

Comment: Tranquilo é assim por causa da queda do trema em algumas palavras, igual a palavra linguiça e outras que usavam trema. Hoje não é mais necessário por conta de reformas ortográficas.

Comment: @sumitani, não entedi vosso comentário. Estás a falar da ortografia ou da pronúncia? Com trema ou sem trema a pronúncia do U em tranqüilo foi sempre a mesma.

Comment: @sidney ortográfico. O tranquilo é diferente da hierarquia na pronuncia do qui, antigamente esta diferença da pronuncia na ortografia era feita pelo trema. Nenhum momento falei sobre mudança da pronuncia, somente da ortografia.